# vimdiff and numbers of diffs

Tags: vimdiff

Suppose I have two files such as :

```
vimdiff file1.txt file2.txt
```

How to find out numbers of differences in the given files?(with hot key or another way)

Comment: I would use `git diff --stat`

Comment: AFAICT vim does not expose an immediate way of counting. You could combine `diff_hlID()` with `synIDattr(_, "name")` to find the Diff groups and count them? Seems error-prone but possible